# SQL with grant option restriction

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-grant

Give permission to user 206 to read and modify the faculty and class tables. This user can authorize others to read and modify class but not faculty.

For the first part to the questions I have:

```
GRANT 
    SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
ON 
    faculty, class
TO 
    U206;
```

I'm not sure how to authorize others to read only class and not faculty though. Is there a restriction to put on when using WITH GRANT OPTION?

Answer (score 2):

You should issue `GRANT`s separately for `class` and `faculty` tables and use `WITH GRANT OPTION` only when granting permissions on `class`

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON class TO u206 WITH GRANT OPTION;
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON faculty TO u206;
```

Now if we login as `u206` we'll be able to grant permissions on `class` to other users

```
mysql> grant select, insert, delete, update on class to u207;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

but won't be able to do the same on `faculty` table

```
grant select, insert, delete, update on faculty to u207;
ERROR 1142 (42000): GRANT command denied to user 'u206' for table 'faculty'
```

Comment: @user2957877 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?